# How to define global variables to be shared later in Julia

Tags: module, global-variables, julia

I have a module in file **global.jl** which defines a global multidimensional array named "data":

```
module Global

    export data

    # GLOBAL DATA ARRAY
    data = zeros(Int32, 20, 12, 31, 24, 60, 5);

end
```

I have a **main.jl** which uses this global variable:

```
include("global.jl")
using .Global

println(data[14,1,15,18,0,1])
```

And I get the following error:

```
$ time /usr/local/julia-1.2.0/bin/julia main.jl
ERROR: LoadError: BoundsError: attempt to access 20Ã12Ã31Ã24Ã60Ã5 Array{Int32,6} at index [14, 1, 15, 18, 0, 1]
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(::Array{Int32,6}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Vararg{Int64,N} where N) at ./array.jl:729
 [2] top-level scope at /usr/home/user/test1/main.jl:4
 [3] include at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [4] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1094
 [5] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:31
 [6] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:295
 [7] _start() at ./client.jl:464
in expression starting at /usr/home/user/test1/main.jl:4
```

I guess I am missing how to share global variables in a separate file in Julia. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Additionally to what @Bill has written (and not related to your question, but I think relevant). First - note that in Julia division of code into files is largely irrelevant. You can define multiple modules in a single file or define a single module in multiple files just fine. Second - if you define some variable in module `A` you are not allowed to rebind it in module `B`. As a consequence you could define your variable `data` as `const` and you would get a code that runs much faster (unless you intend to rebind `data` variable inside module `Global`).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @bogumił-kamiński . I find it really relevant as my question is actually related to how to structure code. I am relatively new to intensive data analysis but I have been working on specific problems for 9 months. I have tried pure Python+numpy+pandas, pure C, a combination of Python+C and Fortran. Each approach has its own advantages and issues. Structuring code is paramount for my problem and way of work. I am looking to a way to have a common large data multidimensional array which is operated by chunks of code, and a main file that can be read and understood easily..

Comment: ... (cont) This means that the main program needs to invoke the different steps that must be in separate files. It is not irrelevant because I can only work structuring code like that. I am glad if other chaps can work with a single file full of methods, I am old-school and I reach a point where I am not productive and I suffer if code is not splitted. And how to structure code is the kind of information that is usually not well covered in documentation because it belongs to  heuristic knowledge rather than descriptive information (which is what you find in documentation).

Comment: As a recap, I am looking for a 'global.jl' which defines data that can be shared across all program code/modules defined in separate 'routine.jl' files, being those separate isolated routines invoked from a 'main.jl'. Ideally the parameters for those routines are passed by reference (same as in Fortran). I am trying to figure out how Julia works in that area as I am just started to evaluate if I can improve my workflow with Julia or I shall fall back to the old options I have tried (python+C or Fortran).

Comment: What you want is perfectly doable using `include`. You do not even have to define modules to get what you want. Have a look at how a top-level file looks in most packages (e.g. https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/blob/master/src/DataFrames.jl) to get the feeling how it works. Also please make sure to read https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/workflow-tips/ as this will be relevant for smooth development.

Comment: Thanks both links help a lot! @bogumił-kamiński

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global is fine--you have a zero index, and Julia array indexes start with 1, not zero, by default:

```
module Global

    export data

    # GLOBAL DATA ARRAY
    data = zeros(Int32, 20, 12, 31, 24, 60, 5);

end

using .Global

function printplus42()
    println((data .+ 42)[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, :])
end

printplus42()


println(data[14,1,15,18,0,1])
```

yields:

```
[42, 42, 42, 42, 42]
ERROR:[...]attempt to access 20×12×31×24×60×5 Array{Int32,6} at index [14, 1, 15, 18, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was so focused trying to find an error in module definition that I missed the fact that all arrays in Julia are base-1 index

Comment: There are three things that can put bugs in my code when porting between python and julia. One is the 0 versus 1 problem as above. The second is ranges, where the end of the range is off by one between Julia and Python, ie 1:3 or range(1,3) is 1,2,3 in julia and 1,2 in python. The third is multidimensional arrays, where Julia iterates (when accessing with one index) column first and Python row first.

Comment: Thanks @bill, duly noted