# Sharing global variables across modules in Julia

Tags: global-variables, julia

With the information kindly provided here: [How to define global variables to be shared later in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57931589/how-to-define-global-variables-to-be-shared-later-in-julia) I keep working on global variables in Julia.

file: **global.jl**

```
module Global

    export data

    data = zeros(Int32, 20, 12, 31, 24, 60, 5);

end
```

file: **main.jl**

```
# MAIN PROGRAM

# INCLUDE GLOBAL
include("global.jl")
import .Global

println(">> Main Before include test.jl")
println(">> ", Global.data[ 14, 1, 15, 18, 1, 1])

include("test.jl")

println(">> Main After include test.jl")
println(">> ", Global.data[ 14, 1, 15, 18, 1, 1])
```

file: **test.jl**

```
module Test

        include("global.jl")
        import .Global

        println("   >> Inside Test")
        println("     ", Global.data[ 14, 1, 15, 18, 1, 1])
        Global.data[ 14, 1, 15, 18, 1, 1] = 123456
        println("     ", Global.data[ 14, 1, 15, 18, 1, 1])

end
```

What I expect is that module Test will modify the Global array `data` and therefore it will later be reflected by `main.jl`. I am obviously still missing something as this is the output:

```
$ /usr/local/julia-1.2.0/bin/julia main.jl
>> Main Before include test.jl
>> 0
   >> Inside Test
     0
     123456
>> Main After include test.jl
>> 0
```

Comment: Hey! If you are looking to tap into more Julia brain power, consdier joining julialang.slack.com if you aren't already a part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key issue you need to understand is that `include` works like copy-paste.

In you code you define module `Global` twice. Once in `Main` module, and once in `Test` module. These two modules have the same code but are separate (the latter is nested in `Test` module). See:

```
julia> Main.Test.Global.data[ 14, 1, 15, 18, 1, 1]
123456

julia> Main.Global.data[ 14, 1, 15, 18, 1, 1]
0
```

This is the way you should define the `Test` module to reuse the `Global` module defined earlier:

```
module Test
        import ..Global
        println("   >> Inside Test")
        println("     ", Global.data[ 14, 1, 15, 18, 1, 1])
        Global.data[ 14, 1, 15, 18, 1, 1] = 123456
        println("     ", Global.data[ 14, 1, 15, 18, 1, 1])
end
```

Comment: Thanks, `include` and `import` usage makes sense now.