# Why can I change the value of an array from another module but not the value of a variable

Tags: global-variables, julia

I have a module that I would like to use as a set of Global variables.

file **Global.jl**:

```
module Global

    export data
    export dataLoaded

    data = zeros(Int32, 20, 12, 31, 24, 60, 5);

    dataLoaded = false;

end
```

file **main2.jl**:

```
include("Global.jl")
import .Global


println(Global.data[10,1,1,1,1,1])
println(Global.dataLoaded)

Global.data[10,1,1,1,1,1] = 5
println(Global.data[10,1,1,1,1,1])

Global.dataLoaded = true
println(Global.dataLoaded)
```

I was not expecting that `dataLoaded` can not be changed in the same way `data` is. Is there any way to allow changing `dataLoaded`?

```
$ /usr/local/julia-1.2.0/bin/julia main2.jl
0
false
5
ERROR: LoadError: cannot assign variables in other modules
Stacktrace:
 [1] setproperty!(::Module, ::Symbol, ::Bool) at ./Base.jl:14
 [2] top-level scope at /usr/home/.../main2.jl:11
 [3] include at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [4] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1094
 [5] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:31
 [6] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:295
 [7] _start() at ./client.jl:464
in expression starting at /usr/home/.../main2.jl:11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have commented in [How to define global variables to be shared later in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57931589/how-to-define-global-variables-to-be-shared-later-in-julia) you are not allowed to change a binding of a variable from outside the module.

First, to explain what is going on consider:

```
x = [1,2,3]
x[1] = 10
```

The second operation `x[1] = 10` does not change a binding of `x`, it only changes the value stored in the first element of vector `x` (as vectors are mutable).

On the other hand writing:

```
y = 1
y = 10
```

First defines `y` to have a value `1` (of type `Int` which is immutable), and then `y = 10` rebinds `y` to hold `10`.

Now - how you can solve your problem. There are two approaches:

The first is to define a setter function inside your `Global` module like this:

```
function setdataloaded(value::Bool)
    global dataLoaded = value
end
```

As `setdataloaded` is defined in `Global` module it can change the bindings of variables in this module. Then you can call `setdataloaded` from outside of the module to change the value of `dataLoaded`.

The second is to use a mutable container instead of an immutable one. The simplest is `Ref`. So you can define:

```
dataLoaded = Ref(false)
```

and then you can get is value as `dataLoaded[]` and set its value like `dataLoaded[] = true` from outside of the `Global` module (because this time you are mutating the contents of the container and not rebinding `dataLoaded`).

**EDIT**

As noted in the comment technically you can evaluate `dataLoaded = 10` expression within `Global` module even from code outside of this module by writing:

```
@eval Global dataLoaded = 10
```

or

```
Global.eval(:(dataLoaded = 10))
```

using the fact that each module (except `baremodule` but this is a rare use case) has its own module-local definition of `eval`.

In a way the `eval` approach is a kind of first approach I have described (using a setter function) that is allowed by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot both for the answer and for the patience of further elaborating your first comment. With your original comment, this further explanation and some reading in Google I understand now how it works. I do not understand though the benefits of not letting to rebind a variable -which has been explicitly exported- from another module (but I can guess there was a reason/benefit to do so).

Comment: Per https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/23295#issuecomment-323476355 it theoretically it could be allowed. Also you could write `@eval Global dataLoaded = true` to rebind the variable in other module (I will add this comment to the answer). For me the main benefit, as a package developer, is that I can assume that except the user makes "extra effort" I can safely assume that globals within the module I develop are not rebinded outside of it.

Comment: As an additional node - you should really avoid using globals in Julia (except if they are `const`) as they are likely to kill the performance of your code.

Comment: I am using globals to store a large array (200/300Mb) which is actually used as an in-memory temporary database for the whole analysis. Other than that, I wanted to use a variable to flag if data was loaded into memory or not (to skip the data-loading for that part) and to store parameters. So basically the only variable which will be intensively (actually really intensively) accessed is the data array. I am probably biased from my past C exposure, where I would follow this approach of putting those variables in a global.c file and accessing those variables from other modules via `extern`.

Comment: (cont).  @bogumił-kamiński I am reading about performance tips with globals and now I am really confused. I will probably ask more about this in other posts or do some performance tests. Also the way I use Globals is actually just a module which exposes a multidimensional array `data`. I am not sure if that qualifies for "global" in Julia. I will probably need to read more about this to fully understand how it works because I am concerned about the performance penalty but can not find another way to share a large array across all modules (all modules use the same array).

Comment: Your `data` qualifies as `global` - that is why I have added the comment. You should make `data` a `const` - and then all will be fast. The rule is that the compiler must know the type of a variable at compile time for Julia to be fast. Adding a `const` qualifier in front of a global guarantees to the compiler that this invariant is met. Note though that when you declare a global variable as `const` you should not rebind it (even within a module). But I think it should not be a problem for your case.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/JuliaStdlibs/Random.jl/blob/master/src/RNGs.jl#L295 for example. This is how you use a `global` `const` in Julia (in this case it is a global random number generator and it is fast).